Mongodb C# driver : Aggregate not using created indexes
I am building an aggregate using the mongodb C# driver that finds documents in the first collection and then finds those from the second collection related to the documents of the first collection. My problem is that it does not seem to use the created indexes to optimize the query.
I tried to use the Hint attribute in AggregateOptions to force it to use the Serial and CreatedDate indexes, though it does not seem use them. I also created an index that has both attributes Serial_CreatedDate.  Is there another way to force the query to use indexes? If not, is there something I can do to optimize this query?
Here is the code snippet related to my issue :
          var toDateFilter = Builders<MessageLogData>.Filter.Lte(ClassExtension.GetPropertyName<MessageLogData>(x => x.CreatedDate), to);
          var serialFilter = Builders<MessageLogData>.Filter.Eq(ClassExtension.GetPropertyName<MessageLogData>(x => x.Serial), args.Serial);
          var combinedFilter = Builders<MessageLogData>.Filter.And(serialFilter, fromDateFilter, toDateFilter);
          // Lookup stage : Lookup with projection for FilesLog
          string filesLogColName = "filesLog";
          AggregateOptions aggOptions = new AggregateOptions();
          aggOptions.Hint = new BsonDocument { { "Serial", 1 }, { "CreatedDate", 1 } };
          var cursor = MessageLogDB.Table.Aggregate(aggOptions)
            .Match(combinedFilter)
            .Lookup(
              _fileTableLog,
              ClassExtension.GetPropertyName<MessageLogData>(x => x.MessageID),
              ClassExtension.GetPropertyName<MessageLogFileData>(x => x.MessageID),
              filesLogColName
            ).ToCursorAsync().Result;

Here is the explain output of the query :
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "SecureLocale.MessagesLog",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "Serial" : {
                                    "$eq" : NUUID("2a8a4eb1-1d16-4358-b494-783446493595")
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "CreatedDate" : {
                                    "$lte" : ISODate("2024-07-04T04:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "CreatedDate" : {
                                    "$gte" : ISODate("2024-01-01T05:00:00.000Z")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "queryHash" : "E5A045D8",
                    "planCacheKey" : "47B5F5E0",
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "Serial" : 1,
                                "CreatedDate" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "Serial_CreatedDate",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "Serial" : [],
                                "CreatedDate" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "Serial" : [ 
                                    "[BinData(3, B14E8A2A161D5843B494783446493595), BinData(3, B14E8A2A161D5843B494783446493595)]"
                                ],
                                "CreatedDate" : [ 
                                    "[new Date(1704085200000), new Date(1720065600000)]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "FilesLog",
                "as" : "filesLog",
                "let" : {
                    "filesLogMsgID" : "$MessageID",
                    "serial" : "$Serial"
                },
                "pipeline" : [ 
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "$expr" : {
                                "$and" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "$eq" : [ 
                                            "$Serial", 
                                            NUUID("2a8a4eb1-1d16-4358-b494-783446493595")
                                        ]
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "$eq" : [ 
                                            "$MessageID", 
                                            "$$filesLogMsgID"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Computer",
        "port" : 00000,
        "version" : "4.4.20-rc0",
        "gitVersion" : "123123123123123"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}


You say a couple of times that the operation does not seem to be using them. How are you checking? If the operation is taking a long time, which is presumably why you're looking into it and asking the question, what does the slow query log file from the database report when executing the query?

@user20042973 I'm checking by replicating the same query  using mongodb commands in the DB manager application. The query is much slower than if I just make a query to get the documents from the first collection and then make a query in the second collection for each found document.

@user20042973 When I replicate the query using mongodb shell commands, I add the .explain() command and check what it returns.

how such fields Serial and CreatedDate are represented in db?

@dododo Serial has the type .NET UUID (Legacy) and CreatedDate has the typical mongodb Date type.

I meant name format, mostly db side uses lower camel case

@dododo In our case it's in pascal case. The filesLog is in lower camel case but it's not a field in either collection.

you should provide explain result, but mostlikely what you can see in the shell is only about first 20 records (batchsize by default is 20) in the batch, where the above c# code iterate all records (20 + 20 + ..).

Also, never use .Result, it can cause many issues

overall you should provide more evidences about why you decided what you did

Agreed we need explain output. Do you have an index on the MessageID field in the second collection? (Minor note for @dododo - annoyingly the display batch size in the shell, which is indeed 20, is different than the batch size used when communicating with the database which is 101 for the initial find. What you say overall though about comparing first batch versus total execution sounds right).

I just added the explain output of the query @user20042973

@user20042973 There is an index for MessageID field in the second collection

@dododo What should I use if .Result can cause many issues?
